# On the definition of Locally Euclidean Spaces

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I'm reading "An Introduction to Manifolds" by Tu, and the author defines $M$ to be locally Euclidean if for every $p \in M$, there is a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\phi : U \to V\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a homeomorphism.
My first question is, the definition of open $U$ is in relation to $M$ or to $\mathbb R^n$ ? I presume that it's in relation to $M$. Am I correct?

Secondly, how can one prove that, say, a triangular mesh in 3D space is actually a Manifold? Is it also a smooth Manifold?

Just to clarify. A triangular mesh is just a collection of triangules glued together by their edges. So, it's a 2D surface embedded in 3D space.

Comment: $U$ should be open in $M$ and $V$ should be open in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks @Berci! Appreciate it

Comment: To follow up @Berci's comment, I would assume there is no a priori requirement that $M$ is a subset of some Euclidean space. Incidentally, you didn't say what $M$ is -- a metric space? a topological space (possibly also Hausdorff and/or second countable and/or $\ldots)$? a Banach space?

Comment: Could you give a more precise definition of what you mean by a 'triangular mesh'?

Comment: In order for the question 'Is this a smooth manifold' to make complete sense, you should start by explicitly defining a topological space. Then check whether or not it is second-countable and Hausdorff (sometimes different conditions are used in the definition), then establish that it is locally Euclidean of a given dimension and see if there is a sensible choice of smooth atlas to give it the structure of a smooth manifold. There is still a certain amount of ambiguity in your description. For example, are you including the boundary? Using the relative topology from $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! The lack of context was actually part of my lack of knowledge! I actually was not realizing the nuance related to the existence of a boundary. Also, my knowledge of triangular meshes is "empirical", but I do know that a trig mesh can be "ill-formed". Actually, I remember that when I coded meshes for numerical methods, I often had to check if they were "manifolds".

Answer (score 1):

In order for a triangular mesh to be a two-dimensional manifold, each edge should be the boundary of no more than two triangles. If some edge is the boundary of a single triangle, the manifold will have a non-empty boundary.

There is also a condition on the vertices that is somewhat harder to state. You don't want two tetraedra to meet on a given vertex for example. The triangles that share a vertex should "surround" the vertex, so to speak.

Comment: One can take the lack of definition in the proper arrangement of the triangles as part of the question, cause I myself don't know which conditions would be necessary. :)

Comment: One should add that such a (nonempty) mesh is **never** a smooth submanifold.

Comment: So, a triangular mesh with these regularity conditions is a Smooth Manifold?

Comment: Yes and no. A compact surface always admits a smooth structure compatible with its topology, but that structure is not induced by the one of the ambient space. If it was, you would have a well defined tangent space at every points. But this is not the case at the pointy vertices.